# Zoom and Center a WMS request in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I applied a CQL filter to get a specific object and used wms/refelct? to display it since I do not know the bounding box, but the result was not good because the object was displayed small and not in the centre.
[http://00.00.00.000:0000/geoserver/wms/reflect?cql_filter=PK='2884'&format=application/openlayers&layers=Name:LAYERNAME&width=800](http://00.00.00.000:0000/geoserver/wms/reflect?cql_filter=PK=%272884%27&format=application/openlayers&layers=Name:LAYERNAME&width=800)

Anybody knows how to filter an object and display it in the centre with zoom?
[image]

Comment: If you are only interested in single features, make a WFS request to get the actual geometry

Comment: Could you please help me to edit the request in an appropriate way?

Comment: make a WFS request for your object - GeoServer will accept a CQL filter and then get the bounds of that and use it in your WMS request

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not practical for our usercase

Comment: Probably the only way to make it work - WMS is a picture